# What are the limit points of $X \times \mathbb{N}$?

Tags: limits, order-topology

Let $X=\{0,1,2 \}$ with natural order topology and give $\mathbb{N}$ its natural order topology. Consider $X \times \mathbb{N}$ with the dictionary order topology.

What are the limit points of $X \times \mathbb{N}$ ?

**Answer:**

$X \times \mathbb{N}=\{(0,1), (0,2), \cdots, (0, \infty), \ (1,1),(1,2), \cdots, (1, \infty), \ (2,1), (2,2), \cdots, (2, \infty) , \cdots \}$

But how to find the limit point?

help me

Comment: Have you tried working with ordinals? Because that would immediately answer this question.

Comment: @DonThousand, Any finite set has all its limits points. But this est $X \times \mathbb{N}$ is discrete set, so it is closed and hence all limits points. Is it?

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure about that. Consider $(3,1)$. Any neighborhood around $(3,1)$ must contain an element of the form $(2,n)$ for some $n\in\mathbb N$. So, $(3,1)$ is a limit point of $X\times\mathbb N$. Again, thinking about this in terms of ordinals makes this problem a lot easier IMO.

Comment: @DonThousand, what are the open sets look like in $ X \times \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Order topology...google is your best friend.

Comment: @DonThousand, I understand that but how exactly look like? Is it like $(a,b) \times (c,d)$ ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91337/discussion-between-don-thousand-and-m-a-sarkar).